# NodeJS - Superagent. SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO when try GET method over HTTPS

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, request, superagent

Following the documentation of an API Service, I have found out that I have to make request to the following URL

https://eipapp1.emeter.com:9674

I am using `superagent` module of Node.JS. And I am getting the following error:

`Error: write EPROTO 140736110642048:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:825:`

I understand that this error is because I am making a Request to the 9674 port but using HTTPS, and thats could be the reason.

There exists a way to make this kind of request? Could be a problem with the API Service specification?

Thanks to all.

Comment: It is very likely that the URL you are trying to access does not support https at all. This kind of error message is typical for cases where one tries to connect to a host:port by https even though only http (or other non-TLS protocols) is supported. Unfortunately, the site is not public so I cannot verify this.

Comment: "because I am making a Request to the 9674 port but using HTTPS, and thats could be the reason. ". No. Typically HTTPS uses port 443 because it has been defined like that by IANA and because the web world does not use `SRV` records to differentiate the service identification from the service location, so a fixed default port is needed. But you can do HTTP or HTTPS over any other port, that works exactly in the same way, if client and server agree. HTTP is (at least for now) layered over TCP (or over TLS layered itself over TCP) and addresses/ports are TCP-level problems, not HTTP(s) ones.